# Are these two pieces functionally equivalent for dataframe's applymap function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to make this run faster? It's very slow for my big dataframe file.

```
            headers = list(df)
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                for header in headers:
                    if len(row[header]) == 1:
                        print("WARNING: single char row value: {} {}".format(header, row[header]))
```

I did this. Is it the same as the for loop above:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: print('WARNING: single char row value: {} {}'.format(x)) if len(x)==1 else x)
```

Comment: Why print out the value instead of using boolean indexing to check if the condition is true or false?

Comment: How to do that using boolean indexing? I want to give a warning message for certain value, or even delete them in the future.

Comment: No, they aren't the same. with boolean indexing: `df[df.applymap(len) == 1]`? What do you mean by *delete them in the future*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is only fast for vectorized operations, so forget about loops. See below for an alternative approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a_more', 'b_more', 'c_more']]*1000000, 
                  columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'])
df['x'][4] = 'a'
df['y'][88888] = 'b'
df['z'][999988] = 'c'
df
```

Gives:
x       y       z
0       a_more  b_more  c_more
1       a_more  b_more  c_more
2       a_more  b_more  c_more
3       a_more  b_more  c_more
4            a  b_more  c_more
...        ...     ...     ...
999995  a_more  b_more  c_more
999996  a_more  b_more  c_more
999997  a_more  b_more  c_more
999998  a_more  b_more  c_more
999999  a_more  b_more  c_more

[1000000 rows x 3 columns]

```
def columnwise_filtered():
    for header in df:
        print(header)
        col = df[header]
        print(col[col.str.len() == 1])
timeit.timeit(lambda: columnwise_filtered(), number=1)
```

Gives:
x
4    a
Name: x, dtype: object
y
88888    b
Name: y, dtype: object
z
999988    c
Name: z, dtype: object

0.8895051459985552

```
def elementwise():
    headers = list(df)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for header in headers:
            if len(row[header]) == 1:
                print("WARNING: single char row value: {} {}".format(header, row[header]))

timeit.timeit(lambda: elementwise(), number=1)
```

Gives:
WARNING: single char row value: x a
WARNING: single char row value: y b
WARNING: single char row value: z c

74.6232932669991

Applymap is twice as fast, but does not give you the cell position:

```
def apply_map():
    df.applymap(lambda x: print('WARNING: single char row value: {}'.format(x)) if len(x)==1 else x)
timeit.timeit(lambda: apply_map(), number=1)
```

Gives:
WARNING: single char row value: a
WARNING: single char row value: b
WARNING: single char row value: c

0.43904865800141124